# JQuery .insertAfter doesn't work in this example - Why?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, html-lists, insertafter

I'm not sure why my jquery code isn't working. I'm creating a Wordpress theme for my company to use, and I can't seem to get the .insertAfter() function working correctly. It just deletes all the content on the page.

```
<div class='entry'>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JQuery Section:

```
$('.entry:first-child').insertAfter($('.entry:last-child'));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.entry:first-child` is selecting the `div` itself, when I imagine it should be selecting the first `ul`. So you are currently trying to insert an element after itself, which doesn't work.

```
console.log($('.entry:first-child')[0] == $('.entry:last-child')[0]); // true
```

Try this...

```
$('.entry ul:first-child').insertAfter('.entry ul:last-child');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/d82Tf/).

You can also see you can just pass the selector string to `insertAfter`, you do not need to wrap it again with `$()`.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Alex. I'd been fiddling with this for a long time, and honestly I thought I had tried your solution. But, turns out I hadn't! Works like a charm. Thanks a ton guys.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.entry ul:first-child').insertAfter($('.entry ul:last-child'));
```

http://jsbin.com/ihihi4/5

As Alex pointed out, you could have used another selector in the .insertAfter call instead of a jquery object.

The jquery documentation is great for explaining this:

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Of note is the subtle difference between insertAfter and after.

http://api.jquery.com/after

The same applies to insertBefore / before and appendTo and append. It's useful to understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusingly-named, as it's not "find the element with the class 'entry' and then select its first child."  The jQuery documentation says, "[First-child] selects all elements that are [themselves] the first child of their parent."  Which in this case is your div.entry.